MySQL server failing to start with error 2003 (HY000)
it's my first time posting as I couldn't find the solution. I tried a lot of the common solutions seen in this website and other websites (like running task manager on admin permission and enabling MySQL in services tab). Thank you so much for your help.
These are the error messages popping up on MySQL Workbench and Command Promptription here](https://i.sstatic.net/iyLS9.jpg)

Tried mysql -u root -p on MySQL, resulted in ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)
Tried on MySQL Workbench, resulted in the application hanging up and error [Errno 13] Permission denied
Tried starting on Task Manager (Admin) and resulted in the status going to "Started" then immediately back to "Automatic"


Does your MySql service is running? Do you use default port?

You test not the server itself but the clients connection. Open MMC, Services applet, and look does MySQL service is running. If not then look at the Error Log.
